# How to create custom collection query in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Hello i create custom module with database i want to show data with filter by somw columns i want to convert  below query OR Can you tell what we do for it 
How to use getSelect()->where() in magento2?
ex:-

```
select * from table where hello_status=1 AND ( location='blabla' OR location='bla')
AND (DATE<='' AND DATE IS NUll )
```

Answer (score 5):

The *Magento 2* SQL query syntax remains the same as in *Magento 1.x* (because they both use the same *Zend* Framework database library).

**For example:**

```
$connection = $this->getConnection();
$select = $connection->select()
    ->from(
        ['o' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
        ['o.product_type', new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')]
    )
    ->where('o.order_id=?', $orderId)
    ->where('o.product_id IS NOT NULL')
    ->group('o.product_type');
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order.php#L93-L101

Comment: How to call module function in block / template file.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Notification\Collection::select() error